# How do I find an $\varepsilon > 0$ so that $x - \varepsilon > k$ implies $x > k$ ($k$ is a constant)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Say I have $x - \varepsilon > k$, and we know that $x > k$, and I want to find some positive term for $\varepsilon$ in terms of $x$ so that once I solve $x - \varepsilon > k$ for $x$, I get $x > k$. One such term is $\varepsilon = \frac{x - k}{2}$, so we have $x - (\frac{x - k}{2}) = \frac{x + k}{2} > k$ which implies that $x + k > 2k$ which means that $x > k$. How do I solve for $\varepsilon$ in order to obtain something like $\varepsilon = \frac{x - k}{2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add $\varepsilon-k$ to both sides of the inequality $x-\varepsilon>k$ to obtain $$x-k>\varepsilon\,,$$ i.e. any $\varepsilon$ will do it between $0$ and $x-k$.

Comment: Why does $\varepsilon$ have to be less than $x-k$? Seems to me the implication "$x-\varepsilon\gt k$ implies $x\gt k$" holds for every positive $\varepsilon$?

Comment: That is true, it does, but if you have $\epsilon > x - k$, then your original inequality doesn't hold: add $k$ and subtract $\epsilon$ from both sides to get $x - \epsilon < k$, in direct contradiction to your original requirement. :)

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$ x - \varepsilon > k $$
where $\varepsilon > 0$.

Add $\varepsilon$ to each side:
$$ x > k + \varepsilon. $$

But since $\varepsilon > 0$, we have $k + \varepsilon > k$. Therefore
$$ x > k + \varepsilon > k, $$
or more simply,
$$ x > k. $$

In short, any $\varepsilon$ such that $\varepsilon > 0$ will do.

Answer (score 0):

You already solved for it.

$\epsilon
=\frac{x-k}{2}
$
will do fine.

What sort of problem
do you have with this?

Comment: I didn't understand where the choice $\varepsilon = \frac{x - k}{2}$ came from. I understood the choice when Berci noted that I could choose anything between $0$ and $x - k$

Comment: That is a convenient choice, being exactly in the middle. You are right about being able to choose anything in that range.